# How fork() will work here?

Tags: operating-system, fork, parent-child

```c
{ 
    if(fork() && fork()) 
    { 
        fork(); 
    } 

    if(fork() || fork()) 
    {
        fork();
    } 

    printf("hello"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I am not getting how `fork()` will behave here and how many times **hello** will be printed.
I just know that `fork() && fork()` will produce total 3 process for 1 parent and similarly, `fork() || fork()` will produce 3 process for 1 parent.

After the 1st `if` condition, 3 processes are created and only parent will enter the if block. Total 4 processes are now there. Now, how to proceed further, I am completely screwed with this?

**If possible, please show a tree diagram .**

Comment: Use a debugger to run your program. And also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) -probably with `-f` option- to understand the involved system calls. BTW, your question looks like a homework. So read carefully about [fork (system call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) then the relevant chapters of http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: BTW, changing the `printf` statement to `printf("hello in %d parent %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());` should be very helpful. And adding a `printf("start pid %d\n", getpid());`  at beginning of program should help a lot.

Comment: At last, you should always keep explicitly the result of `fork` in some local variable, and you should test `fork` against failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tree visualization!**

```
if(fork() && fork()) 
{ 
    fork(); 
}
```

[image: First if block]

Now we have 4 process running in system; **P**, **C1**, **C2** and **C3**.

And Each will execute next if block.

```
if(fork() || fork()) 
{ 
    fork(); 
}
```

[image: Second if block]

In total we will have **4*5 = 20** process running in the system and each will print "Hello".

Answer (score 3):

For first block:

```
if(fork() && fork()) 
{ 
    fork(); 
}
```

Child process receives 0 and skips the if, and the parent proceeds to calculate condition. Parent executes next fork and enters the if block where it forks again. So we have 3 fork invocations resulting in 4 processes.

Then every of these 4 processes executes next block. Let's look at a single one:

```
if(fork() || fork()) 
{
    fork();
}
```

We fork once. The child receives non 0 and condition result is already true, so it enters the if without evaluating second part of the condition and forks there. So we have 2 fork invocations already. Parent process has to evaluate second fork in the expression and it's child enters the if and forks again. So 2 more fork invocations. Total 4 calls which result in 5 running processes.

So each of 4 processes from first block forks in-to 5 processes in second block resulting in total of 4*5 = 20 processes. And each one prints "hello".

Comment: Can you plz elaborate 2nd part ?

Comment: You really should try to do that yourself. just keep in mind that logic expressions are evaluated lazily.

Comment: Thanks ! i visualized it by a tree method.

Comment: ```and the child proceeds to calculate condition. ``` Doesn't It is the child who receives "0", and calculation is skipped?
It is the parent which will execute next fork();

Comment: @amaneureka, thank you for your correction. I've fixed the answer.